# Tesseract OCR crashs on GetUTF8Text() if in Thread (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, tesseract, crash-dumps

i use Tesseract to read numbers from an image.
This works as long as I do everything in one thread. As soon as i outsource the tesseract initialization and recognition to a separate thread, my program crashes when calling the ****GetUTF8Text**()** method.

Im using Tesseract 4.1.1 with leptonica-1.78.0 on a Windows 10 x64 System. My Programm is a x64 QT-App.

Here is my code:

```
screenshot(_image);                            //taking a Screenshot from Desktop
cv::Mat imgBlackWhite;                         //will later hold the Screen in Black/White
cv::Rect asRect = cv::Rect(580, 1035, 36, 20); //to extract a sub-image 

//setup tesseract
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *tessAPI = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
tessAPI->Init(NULL, "eng", tesseract::OEM_LSTM_ONLY);
tessAPI->SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_AUTO);
tessAPI->SetVariable("user_defined_dpi", "300");
tessAPI->SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789.");



cv::Mat subASImg(_image, asRect);                    // creating the image for tesseract

cvtColor(subASImg, imgBlackWhite, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

cv::resize(imgBlackWhite, imgBlackWhite, cv::Size(imgBlackWhite.cols * 3, imgBlackWhite.rows * 3));
cv::threshold(imgBlackWhite, imgBlackWhite, 100, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);

//Send image to recognition engine of tesseract
tessAPI->SetImage(imgBlackWhite.data, imgBlackWhite.cols, imgBlackWhite.rows, 1, imgBlackWhite.step);

//print the detected result:  ----> CRASH
qDebug() << tessAPI->GetUTF8Text();  // ----> CRASH (Access violation) 

tessAPI->End();
```

It's working if I do the exact same thing in the main thread of my program.

Can anyone help here?